# forkJoin not working with dynamic array of URLs in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';



    reqArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {

                this.reqArray.push(this.companyLocationService.locationsUpdate());

      }




forkJoin(this.reqArray).subscribe(
       data => {


            console.log(data);

       },
       err => console.error(err)
    );
```

When I pass data without the for loop in a static way, it works fine.

```
forkJoin(
    this.reqArray.push(this.companyLocationService.locationsUpdate(1)),
    this.reqArray.push(this.companyLocationService.locationsUpdate(2)),
    this.reqArray.push(this.companyLocationService.locationsUpdate(3))
).subscribe(
    data => {

        console.log(data);

    });
```

But, in my case I would have to create URLs array based on a few conditions, so adding it statically won't be possible.
 how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you put below line of codes inside a function and call that function after this.reqArray.push(this.companyLocationService.locationsUpdate()) line:-

forkJoin(this.reqArray).subscribe(
       data => {

```
        console.log(data);

   },
   err => console.error(err)
);
```

Hope this helps you out.